# video streaming using ximagesrc in GStreamer with python bindings

Tags: python, video-streaming, gstreamer, pygtk, pygobject

i am trying to get the screen of my desktop and stream it to my laptop.
for this i have written the below codes. but seems they are not connecting or don't sending the data.

here is my code

in the sender side

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: latin-1
import sys
import os
import gtk
import time
import datetime
import gobject, pygst
pygst.require("0.10")
import gst
pipeline = gst.Pipeline("client")
source = gst.element_factory_make("ximagesrc", "source")
source.set_property("use-damage", "false")
pipeline.add(source)
def new_mux_pad(mux, pad, islast):
    pad.link(mux.get_pad("mpeg"))
    mux = gst.element_factory_make("dvddemux", "mux")
    mux.connect("new-muxed-pad", new_mux_pad)
    pipeline.add(mux)
    src.link(mux)
def new_mpeg_pad(mpg, pad, islast):
    pad.link(mpeg.get_pad("theora"))
    mpeg = gst.element_factory_make("mpeg2dec", "mpeg")
    mpeg.connect("new-mpeged-pad", new_mpeg_pad)
    pipeline.add(mpeg)
    mux.link(mpeg)
def new_theoraenc_pad(thr, pad, islast):
    pad.link(theora.get_pad("ogg"))
    theora = gst.element_factory_make("theoraenc", "theora")
    theora.connect("new-theoraenced-pad", new_theoraenc_pad)
    pipeline.add(theora)
    mpeg.link(theora)
def new_ogg_pad(og, pad, islast):
    ogg = gst.element_factory_make("oggmux", "ogg")
    ogg.connect("new-ogged-pad", new_ogg_pad)
    pipeline.add(ogg)
    theora.link(ogg)
    client = gst.element_factory_make("tcpclientsink", "client")
    pipeline.add(client)
    client.set_property("host", "10.3.100.207")
    client.set_property("port", 8080)
    ogg.link(client)
pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
loop = gobject.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

And code for my receiver is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: latin-1
import gobject, pygst
pygst.require("0.10")
import gst
def new_decode_pad(dbin, pad, islast):
    pad.link(decode.get_pad("xvimagesink"))
    pipeline = gst.Pipeline("server")
    tcpsrc = gst.element_factory_make("tcpserversrc", "source")
    pipeline.add(tcpsrc)
    tcpsrc.set_property("host", "10.3.100.207")
    tcpsrc.set_property("port", 8080)
    decode = gst.element_factory_make("decodebin", "decode")
    decode.connect("new-decoded-pad", new_decode_pad)
    pipeline.add(decode)
    tcpsrc.link(decode)
def new_xvimage_pad(ximg, pad, islast):
    xvimage = gst.element_factory_make("xvimagesink", "imagesink")
    xvimage.connect("new-xvimaged-pad", new_xvimage_pad)
    pipeline.add(xvimage)
    decode.link(xvimage)
pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
loop = gobject.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

when i run this codes i don't get any output.